# How do I draw a B+ tree with tikz in latex with more than 4 Key value pair in a node

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm using

```
child {node {1 \nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 4 \nodepart{five} 5 \nodepart{six} 7}}
```

to create a node in btree. However it seems that `\nodepart{five}` and `\nodepart{six}` get ignored and the rest gets cut off (KVP 5 and 6 do not show up).

How do I draw more than 4 KVPs?

Comment: Can you turn your code into a complete compilable example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using multi-part rectangular nodes with the `shapes.multipart` library, the shape can be split into a maximum of twenty parts. However, only four boxes are allocated by default.

To use the `rectangle split` shape with more than four boxes, the extra boxes must be allocated first, and this can be done using the key `rectangle split parts=<number>`.

A little example: on the left the wrong result (only the default four parts are shown and the last two are lost); on the right, the correct output (after using `rectangle split parts=6`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle split] 
  at (0,0)
  {a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c\nodepart{four}d\nodepart{five}e\nodepart{six}f};
\node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=6] 
  at (2,0)
  {a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c\nodepart{four}d\nodepart{five}e\nodepart{six}f};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your wording suggests the example is going to demonstrate `rectangle split allocate boxes`, but there's no mention of that key in the example.

Comment: @RobKennedy You're right. I've corrected the example. Thnaks.