# TikZ: Draw a B+ Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

Having consulted [How do I draw a B+ tree with tikz in latex with more than 4 Key value pair in a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20773/how-do-i-draw-a-b-tree-with-tikz-in-latex-with-more-than-4-key-value-pair-in-a) and [How do I draw a B+ tree in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/how-do-i-draw-a-b-tree-in-latex) threads, I think the multipart feature of TikZ might just do what I need (see picture below). Is there any way to hide the vertical lines between node parts and still be able to access the multipart anchors (possibly even draw those circles)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there's a key `rectangle split draw splits=<true/false>`. The multipart nodes are well described in the [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

Comment: No kidding. Before posting this question I checked the manual and seem to have successfully managed to overlook that specific key. Thanks.

Comment: @jake Can you write an answer so that I can reach my daily vote cap? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tinkered a little with your problem and came up with a non-automatic version. The fact that the nodes are named with words ( `one` ) instead of numbers ( `1` ) didn't help my attepts to automate it ;)

If you have a splitnode called `myname`, then you need to call `\drawdots` with the two parameters node name and split count.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\dotradius}{0.05}

\newcommand{\drawdots}[2]{% node, recparts
    \foreach \x/\n in {1/{one }, 2/{two }, 3/{three }, 4/{four }, 5/{five }, 6/{six }, 7/{seven }, 8/{eight }, 9/{nine }, 10/{ten }, 11/{eleven }, 12/{twelve }, 13/{thirteen }, 14/{fourteen }, 15/{fifteen }, 16/{sixteen }, 17/{seventeen }, 18/{eighteen }, 19/{nineteen }} 
    {\ifthenelse{#2>\x}{\fill (#1.\n split) circle (\dotradius);}{}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   recspl/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, rectangle split horizontal, draw, anchor=center, rectangle split draw splits=false},
    conn/.style={out=270,in=90}]

\node[recspl=12] (a) at (0,0)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
    \nodepart{four} 4
    \nodepart{five} 5
    \nodepart{six} 6
    \nodepart{seven} 7
    \nodepart{eight} 8
    \nodepart{nine} 9
    \nodepart{ten} 10
    \nodepart{eleven} 11
    \nodepart{twelve} 12
};
\drawdots{a}{12}

\node[recspl=3] (b1) at (-5,-2)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
};
\drawdots{b1}{3}

\node[recspl=3] (b2) at (-1,-2)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
};
\drawdots{b2}{3}

\node[recspl=3] (b3) at (2,-2)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
};
\drawdots{b3}{3}

\node[recspl=3] (b4) at (6,-2)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
};
\drawdots{b4}{3}

\node[recspl=20] (c) at (0,-4)
{   1
    \nodepart{two} 2
    \nodepart{three} 3
    \nodepart{four} 4
    \nodepart{five} 5
    \nodepart{six} 6
    \nodepart{seven} 7
    \nodepart{eight} 8
    \nodepart{nine} 9
    \nodepart{ten} 10
    \nodepart{eleven} 11
    \nodepart{twelve} 12
    \nodepart{thirteen} 13
    \nodepart{fourteen} 14
    \nodepart{fifteen} 15
    \nodepart{sixteen} 16
    \nodepart{seventeen} 17
    \nodepart{eighteen} 18
    \nodepart{nineteen} 19
    \nodepart{twenty} 20
};
\drawdots{c}{20}

\draw[conn] (a.one split) to (b1.one north);
\draw[conn] (a.four split) to (b2.two north);
\draw[conn] (a.six split) to (b3.two north);
\draw[conn] (a.ten split) to (b4.one north);

\draw[conn] (b1.one split) to (c.two north);
\draw[conn] (b2.one split) to (c.seven north);
\draw[conn] (b3.two split) to (c.nine north);
\draw[conn] (b4.one split) to (c.seventeen north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite an old topic, but I've came to this problem recently.
This is my solution, but remember I do not master Latex or Tikz. So I'm sure many things could be done in a better way...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, trees, calc, positioning}
\tikzstyle{key} = [
    circle,
    fill = white,
    dotted,
    thick,
    draw
]
\tikzstyle{vazio} = [
    draw = none,
    fill = none,
]
\tikzstyle{no} = [
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts = #1,
    rectangle split draw splits = false,
    rounded corners,
    fill = black!15,
    draw = black!85,
    thick,
    anchor = center,
    minimum height = 1.8em,
]
\tikzstyle{no b} = [
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts = #1,
    rectangle split empty part width = 1.3ex,
    rectangle split draw splits = false,
    rounded corners,
    fill = black!15,
    draw = black!85,
    thick,
    anchor = center,
    minimum height = 1.8em,
]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent} = [
    thick,
    -latex,
    draw = black,
]
\tikzset{
    child/.style = {
        edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode.west)
            ++(0.06cm+#1*0.65cm, -0.18cm) -- 
            (\tikzchildnode)},
    },
    nil/.style = {
        edge from parent = {thick, -square, draw = gray},
    },
}

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7, transform shape]
    \tikzstyle{every node} = [no b]
    \tikzstyle{level 1} = [sibling distance = 11cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2} = [sibling distance = 2.7cm]
    \node (tree) {42}
        child[child = 0] {node {19 \nodepart{two} 33}
            child[child = 0] {node {10 \nodepart{two} 15 \nodepart{three} 16
                \nodepart{four} 18}}
            child[child = 1] {node {22 \nodepart{two} 27 \nodepart{three} 29}}
            child[child = 2] {node {35 \nodepart{two} 40}}
        }
        child[child = 1] {node {61 \nodepart{two} 74 \nodepart{three} 85 
                \nodepart{four} 95}
            child[child = 0] {node {47 \nodepart{two} 49 \nodepart{three} 53}}
            child[child = 1] {node {65 \nodepart{two} 68 \nodepart{three} 72}}
            child[child = 2] {node {77 \nodepart{two} 81}}
            child[child = 3] {node {88 \nodepart{two} 90 \nodepart{three} 93
                \nodepart{four} 94}}
            child[child = 4] {node {97 \nodepart{two} 98}}
        }
    ;
    \draw [latex-, thick] (tree) -- ++ (0, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps someone and perhaps someone can show me a better way to accomplish this task... :)

Comment: You should consider using `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).